# Can I Resize Form in LWUIT MIDLET?

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit

Is it possible to set size for Form in Midelt program ? i want to show like a half size window in mobile screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to resize the `Form`? Use transparent `Form` and add the `Container` on that `Form`. Set the preferredH of this container as you want.